# Register form PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am a beginner in PHP & MySQL, I am trying to create this register form for a project I am working on currently, here is the PHP script, btw.. If there is a lot of mistakes, it is because I have just started!

The problem I am having is that it does not check the database if the email or username match, because if it did, it should reject.

PHP code:

```
    <?php

//register php

error_reporting(0);

$regUsername = $_POST['reg-username'];
$regEmail = $_POST['reg-email'];
$regPassword = $_POST['reg-password'];

if(isset($regUsername) && isset($regEmail) && isset($regPassword)){
        $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        $selectDB = mysql_select_db('supermazad');
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$regUsername', '$regEmail', '$regPassword')");
        $checkIfSame = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username AND email LIKE '$query' ");
        echo '<h1 class="successMessage">You have successfully registered!</h1>';
}
            if($regUsername || $regEmail == $checkIfSame){
            echo '<h1 class="errorMessage">The username or e-mail already exists.</h1>';
        }

?>
```

Comment: First of first of first, why you debug your code with `error_reporting(0)` Turn it to `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and add `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` to see what happen in your code.

Comment: If you just started, you might as well to it right from the start and don't use `mysql_*`. This has been deprecated for over 2 years now. Try MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: `$checkIfSame = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username AND email LIKE '$query' ");`... what is this ? `username AND email LIKE '$query' `

Comment: if($regUsername == $checkIfSame || $regEmail == $checkIfSame)

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions anymore. As of PHP 5.3, they are deprecated. As of PHP 7.0, they are completely deleted. You should learn with `PDO` class (PHP Data Objects)

Comment: Also this snipped has a serious vulnerability of [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to check if the username and email already exist in the database **after** inserting the username and email into the database. You should check beforehand either via a select with the username and email provided in the registraton, or by placing a unique key constraint on username and email fields.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please use mysqli instead of mysql because it's safer
2. remove error_reporting(0)
3. don't use "like" because it might have many result
4. syntax error on the mysql query

try this one just debug if there are error but I think this works

```
    $regUsername    = $_POST['reg-username'];
$regEmail       = $_POST['reg-email'];
$regPassword    = $_POST['reg-password'];

if(isset($regUsername) && isset($regEmail) && isset($regPassword)){
        $mysqli         = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","supermazad") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
        $queryInsert    = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) 
                            VALUES 
                          ('$regUsername', '$regEmail', '$regPassword')"; 
        mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryInsert); //this will insert the data from db

        $queryUser  = "SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE username = '$regUsername' AND email = '$regEmail'"; // this will authenticate and uses an exact match
        $result     = $mysqli->query($queryUser);
        $row        = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        echo '<h1 class="successMessage">You have successfully registered!</h1>';
}
            if($regUsername == $row['username'] && $regEmail == $row['email']){ //this check if email and username are match with database $row['username'] store username from mysql field and $row['email'] do the same
            echo '<h1 class="errorMessage">The username or e-mail already exists.</h1>';
        }
```

by the way this is normal for a beginner but please improve your coding in the near future, make it cleaner and organize

Comment: try to use https://www.diffchecker.com/ paste your old script on the left and the new script on the right to review what is your mistake. Also please make my answer correct for points hehehe

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like this after `$selectDB = mysql_select_db('supermazad');`:

```
$checkIfSame = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '".$regUsername."' OR email LIKE '".$regEmail."' ");
if (mysql_num_rows($checkIfSame ) > 0) {
    echo '<h1 class="errorMessage">The username or e-mail already exists.</h1>';
} else {
    //insert new user here
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$regUsername', '$regEmail', '$regPassword')");
}
```

Also, you have this in your post :

> if the email or username match

so you should be using `OR`, not `AND`

Comment: Hello @JanLeeYu , I have made a few tweaks and now it works, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$checkIfSame = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '".$regUsername."' OR email LIKE '".$regEmail."' ");
if (mysql_num_rows($checkIfSame ) > 0) {
    echo '<h1 class="errorMessage">The username or e-mail already exists.</h1>';
} else {
    //insert new user here
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$regUsername', '$regEmail', '$regPassword')");
}
```